# I can't get the Collection View Programming topics tutorial to work with XCode 5

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have done the Collection View Programming Topics three times now. Step by step, but there is no way I am getting any content in the collection view.

The thing I have noted for the bindings of the NSText Labels when I bind them to representedObject. is that they get an exclamation mark.

I have tried to set model key paths, xcode identifier, and title to no avail.

I also get an extra view in addition to the collection view item.

I hope anybody has an idea.

I have asserted that the labels have fonts, and that the gridview has 0 rows and 1 column.

Here is AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property NSMutableArray *personModelArray;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
// To see if personModelArray is populated.
- (IBAction) showElements:(id) sender ;
@end
```

Here is AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Occupations

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "PersonModel.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize personModelArray;

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    PersonModel * pm1 = [[PersonModel alloc] init];
    pm1.name = @"John Appleseed";
    pm1.occupation = @"Doctor";

    PersonModel * pm2 = [[PersonModel alloc] init];
    pm2.name = @"Jane Carson";
    pm2.occupation = @"Teacher";

    PersonModel * pm3 = [[PersonModel alloc] init];
    pm3.name = @"Ben Alexander";
    pm3.occupation = @"Student";

    NSMutableArray * tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:pm1, pm2, pm3, nil];
    [self setPersonModelArray:tempArray];
    /*
    for (PersonModel *obj in personModelArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", obj.name, obj.occupation) ;
    }
     */
    //  NSLog(@"Awoken from nib %@",personModelArray) ;

}
// Convenience: hooked up with a button to see that
// the contents of the array is still there!
-(void)showElements:(id) sender {
    for (PersonModel *obj in personModelArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", obj.name, obj.occupation) ;
    }

}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}
-(void)insertObject:(PersonModel *)p inPersonModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [personModelArray insertObject:p atIndex:index];
}

-(void)removeObjectFromPersonModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [personModelArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

-(void)setPersonModelArray:(NSMutableArray *)a {
    personModelArray = a;
}

-(NSArray*)personModelArray {
    return personModelArray;
}
@end
```

Here is PersonModel.h

```
//
//  PersonModel.h
//  Occupations
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PersonModel : NSObject {
    NSString * name;
    NSString * occupation;
}
@property  NSString * name;
@property  NSString * occupation;


@end
```

Here is PersonModel.m

```
//
//  PersonModel.m
//  Occupations


#import "PersonModel.h"

@implementation PersonModel
@synthesize name;
@synthesize occupation;
@end
```

Comment: Well.. it is not very clear what you want to achieve... Tip for future . it is not good idea to manipulate with object data in AppDelegate class. Create Manager class and let it do you dirty work...

Comment: I want to be able to see contents of an array (two properties per object) in two labels inside a NSCollectionView (grid view).

Comment: For NSCollectionVIew to work you need: set delegate and data source of  collectionView, add 2 methods.. `-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. in the last method you need to do you customization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responce, but I actually think there is a difference between UICollectionView and NSCollectionView. Besides that, the code is pretty much copied straight out of Apple's tutorail on NSCollectionView. Collection View Programming Topics. I suspect that I somehow have done something wrong, but it's time to skim the release notes!

Comment: oh...i'm sorry..mislooked

Comment: Well. You were partially right, I found a project that works here : https://github.com/sulf/CollectionViewExample I haven't populated the "Grid" that came with the NSContent View, a separate view, but I have placated the TextLabels straight into the Collection View. I'm going to sleep before I see if it works! :) Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my greatest blunder in 2013 was that I didn't completely understood how the control (NSContentsView) was supposed to be assembled.

I just stumbled into the tutorial from Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics, and just couldn't make it work. To my defense, first I fickled a little with the bindings, so I supsected the error to still be there somewhere, but nada. I had placed the controls I had bound into the contentsview, and not into the "gridview".